# Scroll to div on click (show div on center screen)

Tags: javascript, scroll, click

I have a question about a tiny JS that I have put at the bottom of the page. The script scrolls to another div when the user clicks on one div. On my website there is a contact button (example below).

```
<div id="contactbutton"></div>
```

When the user of the website clicks on this div, the page scrolls down to another div on the page with a contact form on it (example below).

```
<div id="contactform">
  <form>
    (form content here)
  </form>
</div>
```

I did that using the following JS code at the bottom of the page, that will scroll to the other div:

```
<script>
  $("#contactbutton").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#contactform").offset().top
  }, 500);
  });
</script>
```

The code works perfect, but problem is that I have a *fixed div* header on my website that is on top of everything on the page. When the user scrolls to *#contactform*, a part of this contact form div is behind this header.

I am looking for a way to scroll to *#contactform*. But instead of scrolling all the way, I want it to scroll till it's a certain amount of pixels away from the top of the browser window so it will show below the header and not behind it.

I hope somebody can help me out! Thanks alot in advance.

Elmigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to substract the height of your sticky header from the scroll distance, something like this (`#fixed-header` is an id of your sticky header):

```
<script>
  $("#contactbutton").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#contactform").offset().top - $('#fixed-header').outerHeight()
    }, 500);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Substracting is a great solution, thanks! I was wondering if it was possible to subtract a certain amount of pixels instead?

Comment: `scrollTop: $("#contactform").offset().top - 100` - use your desired number of pixels instead of `100`.

Comment: That's easy! Sorry for asking, I'm not that into coding. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could substract the height of your header so the scroll will stop a few pixels before your content leaving some spaces for the header

```
<script>
  $("#contactbutton").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#contactform").offset().top - $('#header').height()
  }, 500);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! But is there a way to subtract a certain amount of pixels instead of the height of the header div? Or would that be a tricky thing to do considering all the different browser sizes (mobile devices, etc)?

Comment: Also consider that maybe one day you change the height of your header... a fixed number would not help in that situation...